# Android Studio, VD creation error

Tags: android-studio, compiler-errors, virtual-device-manager

I was trying to initialize a virtual device and run into the following error:

> /Users/Oscari/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_23.ini
>   java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:
>   /Users/Oscari/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_23.ini
>
> ...(plenty other errors)

Screenshot:

[image: (Screenshot)]

I tried to check the directory that error points to, seems like part of it is missing:

[image: (Screenshot)]

What could it mean and how I solve it?